What does "って" mean in the phrase "声は出していなくって" in this sentence?

三人は、話してるみたいだけど、声は出していなくって、一人、誰かが手を動かして、いろんな形をやると、次の誰かが、それを見ていて、すぐ、別の何か形を手で、いろいろやって、三人目が、少しやると、突然、とっても面白そうに少し声を出して、大笑いをしたりした。

I've looked at the common uses of "って", but I still don't know what it means here.

This question is similar to: Adverb followed by って. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

According to "a reference grammar of Japanese" by S. martin, -くって is just a lively form of -くて the て形 of i-adjectives. So いなくって stands for いなくて, and here has its coordinative function.
